# Install and configure ffmpeg on Suse 10 (without yum)

Tags: installation, sles, ffmpeg

can someone direct me over a good tutorial on ffmpeg installation on Linux (specifically on Suse 10).
I have to say the `yum install ffmpeg` option is unavaiable, as yum isn't even present on this Linux box.

Furthermore, I have to install a specified set of encoders/decoders for ffmpeg (MPEG1, MP4, AVI, FLV, MOV, WMV, SWF, FLA) with support for high-definition video (up to Full HD) and to install all that stuff in a specific location. So, have you got any guide for this task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get it from [GWDG's FTP site](ftp://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/linux/misc/nix/suse/10.0/).

Comment: But won't it use rpm dependencies that I will, in turn, have to install ?